# this is undefined when calling child function through a parent function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

UPDATE: I have figured out a muuuuch simpler workaround by sing  in the typescript file so the JS parent is no longer needed. ~facepalm~ Thanks for all your suggestions!

I am trying to get a button to trigger the function `affTimer()` inside the child function component but I keep getting the error "this is undefined" in relation to the function call. Here is the two code files:

affType.js

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import affirmationService from '../Services/requestService'
import affTrack from '../audio/inner.wav';
import warn from '../audio/warning.wav';
import Player from '../Player/Player';
import videoBG from '../videos/InnerStrength.mp4';
import Type from '../Type/Type.tsx';
import Button from "../customButton";
import {tXP} from '../Type/Type.tsx';

class affType extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {character: undefined};
    this.child = React.forwardRef();
    this.startGame = this.startGame.bind(this);
    
  }
  
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;

    //let affirmation_id = params.affirmation_id;
    //let response = await affirmationService.getById(affirmation_id);
    //this.setState({character: response.data});
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('overlay_blk_fast').style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById('overlay_blk_fast').style.display = 'none';
      }, 1000);
    }, 10);
  }


  spawnDialog() {
    document.getElementById('overlay_1').style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('overlay_1').style.opacity = 1;
    }, 10);

  }

  destroyDialog() {
    document.getElementById('overlay_1').style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('overlay_1').style.display = 'none';
    }, 1000);
  }
  repeat() {
    document.getElementById('overlay_2').style.opacity = 0;
    document.querySelector('video').play();
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('overlay_2').style.display = 'none';
    }, 1000);
  }

  test_ended() {
    document.getElementById('overlay_2').style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('audio_end').play();
      document.getElementById('overlay_2').style.opacity = 1;
    }, 10);
  }
  startGame() {
      var track = document.getElementById('aff');
      track.play();
      this.child.current.affTimer();
  }

  render() {
      
    return ( 
        <div>
        <div className="contentplayer">
            <audio id='aff'><source src={affTrack} /></audio>
            <video autoPlay muted loop id="myVideo">
           <source src={videoBG} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>      
            <audio id="audio_end" src="/Audio/Inner Strength completed quest - play with completed quest prompt.wav"/>
        </div>
        <p>{tXP}</p>
        <Button 
                border="none"
                color="pink"
                height = "200px"
                onClick={this.startGame}
                radius = "50%"
                width = "200px"
                children = "Start!"
            />
        <Type ref={this.child}> 
           
        </Type>

        <div className="aligntopright" onClick={() => {this.spawnDialog()}}>
          <div className="backbtn-white"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div className="overlay_blk_fast" id="overlay_blk_fast"></div>
        <div className="overlay" id="overlay_1">
          <div className="dialog">
            <div className="dialogcontainer">
              <img className="dialogbg"/>
              <h3 className="dialogtext">Are you sure you would like to go back to the selection page?</h3>
              <h2 className="no" onClick={() => {this.destroyDialog()}}>No</h2>
              <Link to="/affirmation"><h2 className="yes">Yes</h2></Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="overlay" id="overlay_2">
          <div className="dialog">
            <div className="dialogcontainer">
              <img className="dialogbg"/>
              <h3 className="dialogtext">Would you like to repeat this quest?</h3>
              <Link to="/affirmation"><h2 className="no">Go back</h2></Link>
              <h2 className="yes" onClick={() => {this.repeat()}}>Repeat</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default affType;
```

type.tsx

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
import useTypingGame from "react-typing-game-hook";
import { textSpanContainsTextSpan } from 'typescript';

var xpM = 0;
var i = 0;
var err = 0;
var xp = 5;
var tXP = 0;
var addXP = 1;
var bonus = 0;
var bonusCounter = 0;
//var warnP = new Audio({warn});
//var affTrackP = new Audio('../audio/inner.wav');

function TypeF() {

  
  let text_array = [
    "There is strength and solidity within me",
    "Courage is flooding through my veins",
    "I possess strength within my heart",
    "I am leading the charge with courage, and a vigorous resolution",
    "There is a force inside me that is unbelievably powerful",
    "There is a brave, radiant spirit inside me",
    "I am a tall tree, with thick and strong roots",
    "I was born for this",
    "There is a divinity within",
    "I am a force of nature",
    "I possess the mental fortitude of those who climb the highest peaks",
    "I was born with a determined spirit",
    "There is an intensity in my eyes"
  ];
 
  let text = text_array[i];

  const {
    states: {
      charsState,
      length,
      currIndex,
      currChar,
      correctChar,
      errorChar,
      phase,
      startTime,
      endTime
    },
    actions: { insertTyping, resetTyping, deleteTyping }
  } = useTypingGame(text);

  const handleKey = (key: any) => {
    if (key === "Escape") {
      resetTyping();
    } else if (key === "Backspace") {
      deleteTyping(false);
    } else if (key.length === 1) {
      insertTyping(key);
    }
  };

  

  if (currIndex + 1 === length) {
    xpM = xpM + 1;
    bonusCounter = bonusCounter + 1;
    err = err + errorChar;
    addXP = ((xp * correctChar) - (err * 2)) * xpM;
    if (err > correctChar) {
      addXP = correctChar * 3;
    }
    tXP = tXP + addXP;
    if (bonusCounter >= 5) {
      bonus = bonus + 1;
      bonusCounter = 0;
    }
    resetTyping();
  }
  
  var tmr;
  var cd = 18;

  function affTimer() {
    tmr = setInterval(tock, 1000);
    if (i >= text_array.length) {
      clearInterval(tmr);
    }
  }  

  function tock() {
    if (cd > 0) {
      cd = cd - 1;
      console.log(cd);
    }
    else if (cd <= 0) {
      if (i < text_array.length) {
        i = i + 1;
        cd = 18;
        resetTyping();
      }
      else {
        i = text_array.length;
      }
    }
  }


  return (
    
  <div className='container'>
     
  <div
    className="typing-test"
    id="start"
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
        handleKey(e.key);
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
    tabIndex={0}
  >
    {text.split("").map((char: string, index: number) => {
      let state = charsState[index];
      let color = state === 0 ? "white" : state === 1 ? "green" : "red";
      
      return (
        <span
          key={char + index}
          style={{ color }}
          className={currIndex + 1 === index ? "curr-letter" : ""}
        >
          {char}
        </span>
      );
    })}
  </div>
  <h2 className='debug'> TIMER: {cd}, I: {i}, ERRORS: {err},  MULTIPLIER: {xpM}, Type XP: {correctChar * xp}, CurrXP: {correctChar * xp * xpM} XPTotal: {tXP} bonusCounter: {bonusCounter}, BONUS: {bonus}</h2>
</div>
);

}
export {tXP};
export default TypeF;
```

Any help would be amazing, I have been stuck on this for 2 days and it is the last bit I need to complete so I can move to the next phase.

Comment: Surely you meant `this.child = React.createRef();` instead of `this.child = React.forwardRef();`. Other than this, which function are you referring to?

Comment: I want the button in the JS parent to trigger the function ```affTimer()``` in the Type child so it starts running along with the audio clip tied to the button. I tried doing this in the typescript but I couldn't find a way to use the .play() function inside the Type function component.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Yeah, Nicholas' answer is what you need to do if using a React ref to invoke the child's function.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your child component is a function component. You can't get a ref to an instance of a function component, because there is no instance. If you really need to use a function component and also expose some custom object as a ref, then you can use the `useImperativeHandle` hook plus `forwardRef` to define what the parent component should receive on its ref. For example:

```
const Type = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  // ...
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    // The following object is what will get assigned to the 
    //    parent component's this.child.current
    return {
      afftimer: function () {
        tmr = setInterval(tock, 1000);
        if (i >= text_array.length) {
          clearInterval(tmr);
        }
      }  
    }
  });

 // ...
})
```

But `useImperativeHandle` is not a common thing to use. There is likely a more standard way to solve your problem. The normal way for a parent component to tell a child component what to do is with props, not with refs.

Comment: Greatly appreciated! I know there are way better ways to go about this but I was adding to previously existing code and got tho this point without really knowing a lot about React. Since this website is going to stop getting new pages once this typing game is cmplete I am ok with using a not-so-common fix so we can move to the next phase. How would I implement this into my current structure?

Comment: I should clarify, I am just trying to get the parent to tell the child to run the ```affTimer``` method, it doesn't need to pass information or run the function outside the child.